# Pass values instead of range to VBA Function

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function, vba

I am creating VBA functions in Excel 2007.  One has a prototype:

```
Function ToLevelCode_Range(val As Double, ByRef R As Range)
```

I can call it this way just fine and it gets the correct result:

```
=ToLevelCode_Range(B2, Categories!D1:D4)
```

There is an instance, where I want to the second parameter to be a specific set of values:

```
=ToLevelCode_Range(B2, { 0.38, 0.78, 1.18, 1.58 })
```

This results in #VALUE, and I can't even get to the first breakpoint in my function.

I am programmatically generating the spreadsheet, and the number of values in the array is variable, so I can't do it with a function with 5 parameters, etc.  I don't know if VBA has a variable argument list syntax, but that would be an option.

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 3):

ByRef means that you have to pass a reference to (the address of) an existing object as the argument, so it can work with that actual object; vs. ByVal which means you'd pass a value, and that value would be copied into the receiving argument.

So you can't pass a list of values as a reference, you need to create a Range object that holds your values, and then pass the (reference to that) object as that argument.

The problem here is that a `Range` object in Excel is a representation of an actual set of Cells, but I believe the [NamedRange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.namedrange.aspx#Y0) class will allow you to programmatically create a 'virtual' Range object, with virtual cells that contain your values, but I've never used it personally. :)

I believe this question over at StackOverflow is (basically) the same as yours, and worth checking out:

[Microsoft Excel: Programmatically create a hidden named range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2858751/microsoft-excel-programmatically-create-a-hidden-named-range)

Comment: Your googling skills belies your programming instincts.

Comment: @surfasb You know, it took me until now to finally grasp what you meant by that, and how to take that, even after I asked you. :)  In this case, my semi-competent googling skills were used to reassure myself I (still) understood pointers in VBA, and to fill out the answer with links. ;)

Comment: Yeah, I probably should of made the statement "... belies your lack of progamming instincts:)" The contradiction would of made the irony more apparent.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the function parameters to

```
Function ToLevelCode_Range(val As Double, R As Variant)
```

it will accept both a range and an array

Of cource you will need to handle the different data types in the function code

When called as `=ToLevelCode_Range(B2, Categories!D1:D4)` R will be type `Variant/Object/Range`

When called as `=ToLevelCode_Range(B2, { 0.38, 0.78, 1.18, 1.58 })` R will be type `Variant/Variant(1 to 4)`